# Natural frequencies

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, resonance

It's defined as the frequency that an object vibrates at when there is no driving force.
What's a driving force? IS the natural frequency the frequency at which the atoms inside  vibrate? People usually use the example of hitting a baseball bat or striking a tuning. Isn't the hitting a driving force? And when you hit a tuning fork harder, the frequency of the vibration doesn't change. The amplitude changes. Can someone explain that? Does anyone have like a good animation of wave propagating through air and changing amplitude?

Answer (score 2):

If you hit a tuning fork with a hammer, you provide a driving force.  Once your hammer is no longer in contact with the tuning fork, there is no longer any driving force, and the fork vibrates at it's natural frequency.